# Фокус и табуляция C# в MFC

Tags: c#, mfc

Есть проект в MFC, в который встраиваются формы C#.

**1-ая проблема** - `TabIndex` не влияет на фокус, но это не критично.

**2-ая проблема** - после перехода по <kbd>tab</kbd>-у с последнего элемента, программа зависает. / возможно, причина в том что у формы C# `parent = null`.

Как можно решить 2-ую проблему?

p.s. на данный момент пытаюсь встроить элемент в конце, и при `gotFocus` насильно переводить фокус на 1ый элемент.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC - это фреймворк для веб-приложений.
Формы - это десктоп.
Мне слабо понятна связь между этими двум понятиями.

Comment: извиняюсь, опечатался )) **MFC**

Comment: Что именно значит «зависает»? Контролы реагируют на мышь? Или просто «глотается» фокус? А что говорит отладчик?

Comment: > Что именно значит «зависает»?
> Контролы реагируют на мышь? 

полностью перестает реагировать на внешний мир, в том числе контролы не реагируют.

> А что говорит отладчик?

Если нажать на паузу, то переходит на функцию **winocc.cpp** у **mfc**

    BOOL CWnd::IsDialogMessage(LPMSG lpMsg)
    {
 ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));

 if (m_nFlags & WF_OLECTLCONTAINER)
  return afxOccManager->IsDialogMessage(this, lpMsg);
 else
  return ::IsDialogMessage(m_hWnd, lpMsg);
    }

и дальше ничего не говорит, типо все путем, но форма не отвечает.

Comment: Странно. А это вам не поможет: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/75a816e1-ea3f-4163-b4c2-a7d7c87bad70 ?

Comment: @VladD позже посмотрю что там пишут :) спасибо за ответы :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту проблему на данный момент получилось пройти с помощью заплатки, когда добавляю новый контрол имеющий фокус, и при GotFocus перевожу на следующий фокус:

```
    TextBoxVisualizer x = new TextBoxVisualizer();
    x.v_value.Text = "sfaas";
    this.vf_panel.Controls.Add(x);
    x.v_value.GotFocus += delegate
    {
        this.vf_container.SelectNextControl(x, true, true, true, true);
    };
```

если ничего лучшего не найду оставлю этот способ.